# ¿Cómo limitar un KeyEvent a una vez por segundo en Java?

Tags: java, eventos

Buenas.

Un ejemplo para ayudar al entendimiento de la duda:

```
"X usuario presiona la tecla Y"
"X usuario debe esperar 1 segundo para volver a presionar la tecla Y"
```

El tiempo acaba y puede volverla a presionar. ¿Cómo podría implementarse esto en un programa en Java?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: hola bienvenido a la comunidad, te informo que para que tu pregunta sea valida debes publicar un codigo de intento y en base a ese codigo te podran ayudar

Comment: No soy un experto pero puedes usar SetInterval

Comment: ¡Hola! ¡Gracias por el aviso! Sólo buscaba ideas o si existía algún código para mi pregunta cerrada (ya que sólo se limitaba a una funcionalidad) porque no tenía ni idea dónde empezar para implementar un código. Fue por eso que hice la pregunta y al final, conseguí respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedes evitar que los eventos se generan, pero puedes colocar un `Timer` que corre una vez que un evento esta consumido y bloquear lo que **hace** el `Listener` por mientras.

revisa [java.util.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) y `TimerTask`

Si compartes código, te puedo decir más.

Comment: No llegue a compartir un código debido a que sólo buscaba ideas para implementarlo debido a que es un terreno de programación inexplorado aún para mí. Gracias por darme la idea con el Timer, he tardado en responder porque estaba implementando para ver sí me servía la opción y efectivamente me sirvió.